# Drag and drop not perfectly drops within position relative droppable div

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, drag

I have three images to drag and drop into droppable div. While dropping the image into droppable div, the image not perfectly dropped. I need the droppable div as position relative. Removing the position properties in droppable div works perfectly. How can I achieve this with position relative?

```
#droppable {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #EBECED;
  }
```

My code in [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/55uxkLrf/2/)

Comment: Your jsFiddle is very hard to understand. What is the desired functionality? The images only appear once you start dragging, and can only be dropped on themselves.

Comment: @Tim Ogilvy.. Yes just before i notified that, there is the rendering problem in chrome, opera and safari to view the initial design. That is not my problem. Please run my jsfiddle code in Firefox. My issue: can't able to drop the image into droppable div perfectly with position relative..

Comment: It looks like adding the `position: relative` is breaking jQuery's ability to position the elements.  They can also be dragged out of the box when it's not relative. I'd suggest that you are probably overriding some core jquery CSS in the process of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TimOgilvy .. So can you please suggest me any other possibilities to achieve that..? Any codes or any reference link for better for my issue..?

Comment: I can add position relative to the target div at https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#default and it doesn't break.

Comment: @TimeOgilvy.. I have added my updated Jsfiddele [here](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/55uxkLrf/11/) .., now you can understand why i have used the droppable div as position relative. To get the x and y position within the droppable div as start from x:0 and y:0 from the top left corner., i have used this position properties.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

I have changed CSS .Added z-index in draggable/droppable div :

```
#droppable {
      border: 1px solid black;
      height: 250px;
      margin-left: 30%;
      margin-top: -35%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      width: 490px;
      background: #EBECED;
      z-index:1;
  }
```

I have changes img.drag to span.drag because class is assign to span.

```
span.drag {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      position: relative;
      z-index:2;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please note that its not get placed where we drop the image on droppable div..? You can note my point while removing the position as relative in droppable div. Your code works for get escape from hidding the image while drag over the droppable div.. But i need the above said functionalities.. Please help..

Comment: I have added my updated Jsfiddele [here](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/55uxkLrf/11/) .., now you can understand why i have used the droppable div as position relative. To get the x and y position within the droppable div as start from x:0 and y:0 from the top left corner., i have used this position properties.

Answer (score 1):

While append the cloned image into droppable div(with position relative), cloned image gets placed in position (its own position + its parent droppable div offset value), so we need to omit those parent offset values.

#### Below code works for me..

```
ClonedImage.appendTo('#droppable');
        
var parentPostion = $('#droppable');
        
var leftAdjust = ClonedImage.position().left - parentPostion.offset().left;
var topAdjust = ClonedImage.position().top - parentPostion.offset().top;
ClonedImage.css({left: leftAdjust, top: topAdjust});
```

Above functionality works in [Jsfiddle..!](https://jsfiddle.net/arunvalaven/55uxkLrf/13/)